# Mascara em campo html não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Boa tarde,

Tenho uma pagina em minha aplicação para cadastrar clientes , nada fora do normal.

Nesta pagina , tenho alguns campos ( cif ,rg , telefone,telefone_2 ,etc) que ao digitar são formatados com javascript com a seguinte função:

*Transformando o telefone : 1199999999 em (11)9999-9999

// Mascaras Javascript

```
function mascara(o,f){
    v_obj=o
    v_fun=f
    setTimeout("execmascara()",1)
}

function execmascara(){
    v_obj.value=v_fun(v_obj.value)
}

function id( el ){
    return document.getElementById( el );
}

// aqui começa as mascaras 

function mtel(v){ //MASCARA PARA TELEFONE

    v=v.replace(/\D/g,"");             //Remove tudo o que não é dígito
    v=v.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d)/g,"($1) $2"); //Coloca parênteses em volta dos dois primeiros dígitos
    v=v.replace(/(\d)(\d{4})$/,"$1-$2");    //Coloca hífen entre o quarto e o quinto dígitos
    return v;
}

window.onload = function atribuiMascaras(){ // FUNCAO QUE É ACIONADO AO CARREGAR A PAGINA ( WINDOW.ONLOAD )

    id('txtCel').onkeyup = function(){ //ATRIBUI O CAMPO COM ID txtCel A MASCARA DE TELEFONE
        mascara( this, mtel );
    }
```

Acontece que, eu posso acessar essa pagina e ja ter parcialmente os dados desse contato que esta virando um cliente.

Caso eu ja tenha esses dados parciais , ao acessar a pagina  , pego o ID do contato na Url e faço uma chamada num controller para pegar os dados desse cliente.

```
$(document).ready(function selectDadosContato(){        

var id_contato = <?=$dados[0];?>;
var tipo = '<?=$dados[1];?>';

jQuery.ajax
    ({  

        url: "/admin2/controllers/contatos/Contatos.php?id="+id_contato+"&tipo="+tipo, //URL de destino
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        success:
        function(data) {    

                var d = data.data_nascimento;
                var d = d.split('-');
                var data_nasc = d[2] + '/' + d[1] + '/' + d[0];

                document.getElementById('txtNome').value = data.nome;
                document.getElementById('txtCel').value = data.telefone;                    

             } //function(data);    
        });
});
```

Eis que surge meu problema , quando faço a requisição e pego os dados do contato e atribuo o valor recebido nos campos html , eu precisaria que as mascaras dos campos fossem ativadas, mas os campos são preenchidos da maneira que eles vem do banco.

Desde ja, grato

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa https://plugins.jquery.com/jquery.inputmask

```
$(document).ready(
   $("#Cep").inputmask("99999-999");
   $('#telefone').inputmask("(99) 9999-9999[9]");
});
```

Comment: Bom dia Alexandre , realmente não conhecia o plugin. Na doc tem muito material sobre e parece ser bem completo. Deu certinho as mascaras. Obrigada !

Answer (score 1):

Basta atribuir as mascara no retorno do seu `ajax`

```
mascara( document.getElementById('txtCel'), mtel);
```

---

```
jQuery.ajax
    ({  

        url: "/admin2/controllers/contatos/Contatos.php?id="+id_contato+"&tipo="+tipo, //URL de destino
        dataType: "json", //Tipo de Retorno
        success:
        function(data) {    

                var d = data.data_nascimento;
                var d = d.split('-');
                var data_nasc = d[2] + '/' + d[1] + '/' + d[0];

                document.getElementById('txtNome').value = data.nome;
                document.getElementById('txtCel').value = data.telefone;      

                //Chame a sua função de mascara         
                mascara( document.getElementById('txtCel'), mtel);

             } //function(data);    
        });
});
```

Comment: Voce não pode aceitar uma resposta em 6 minutos....  Deu certinho amigo , tinha quebrado a cabeça a tarde tentando resolver isso  hehe . Obrigado !

Comment: @jefeson Assis , uma duvida , tentei chamar a mascara para outro campo : mascara( document.getElementById('txtFixo'), tel); . Ficando assim com a chamada para 2 campos distintos. Mas assim , só funcionou a mascara do campo 'txtFixo' e a do campo 'txtCel' não funcionou .Por que ?

Comment: Não deveria chamar a variável `mtel` - `mascara( document.getElementById('txtCel'), mtel);`? caso não funcione, verifique o console do browser para ver se aparece algum erro

Comment: Bom dia @Jeferson  , erro meu ao digitar. Ainda sim , tentei colocando todas as mascaras ( de cpf,rg , telefone, email , etc )  e somente a ultima mascara chamada é que funciona. No console , ele não apresenta nem um erro ou aviso